# Does Apache Beam's BigQuery IO Support JSON Datatype Fields for Streaming Inserts?

Tags: java, google-bigquery, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm currently working with Apache Beam (Dataflow) to process and insert data into a Google BigQuery table. The table has a field with a JSON datatype (`test_jsontype_field`), and I'm encountering issues during `BigQueryIO.Write.Method.STREAMING_INSERTS`.

**Issue Description:**
My pipeline reads JSON data from GCP PubSub and writes to BigQuery using streaming inserts. I am using `TableRowJsonCoder` to decode the JSON input string into a `TableRow` object. However, when Beam tries to insert data into BigQuery, the process fails with an error: `The field <FIELD> is not a record.` Basically the `<FIELD>` is a JSON datatype in BigQuery schema.

**Question**
Is there known support for JSON datatype fields in BigQuery when using Apache Beam for streaming inserts? If so, are there specific configurations or coding practices required to ensure compatibility?

I would appreciate any insights or guidance on how to handle JSON datatype fields effectively in this scenario with Apache Beam and BigQuery.

**Code**

```
static TableRow convertJsonToTableRow(String json) {
        TableRow row;
        try (InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(json.getBytes())) {
            row = TableRowJsonCoder.of().decode(inputStream, Coder.Context.OUTER);
            logger.debug("message {}", row.toPrettyString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("failed to serialize json to table row: " + json, e);
        }
        return row;
    }
```

**Error**

```
"org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Insert failed: [{"errors":[{"debugInfo":"","location":"test_jsontype_field","message":"This field: test_jsontype_field is not a record.","reason":"invalid"}],"index":0}]
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:39)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BatchedStreamingWrite$BatchAndInsertElements$DoFnInvoker.invokeFinishBundle(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.finishBundle(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1776)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PTransformFunctionRegistry.lambda$register$0(PTransformFunctionRegistry.java:116)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.ProcessBundleHandler.processBundle(ProcessBundleHandler.java:560)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient.delegateOnInstructionRequestType(BeamFnControlClient.java:150)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient$InboundObserver.lambda$onNext$0(BeamFnControlClient.java:115)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UnboundedScheduledExecutorService$ScheduledFutureTask.run(UnboundedScheduledExecutorService.java:163)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Insert failed: [{"errors":[{"debugInfo":"","location":"test_jsontype_field","message":"This field: test_jsontype_field is not a record.","reason":"invalid"}],"index":0}]
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BatchedStreamingWrite.flushRows(BatchedStreamingWrite.java:416)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BatchedStreamingWrite.access$900(BatchedStreamingWrite.java:67)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BatchedStreamingWrite$BatchAndInsertElements.finishBundle(BatchedStreamingWrite.java:286)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Insert failed: [{"errors":[{"debugInfo":"","location":"test_jsontype_field","message":"This field: test_jsontype_field is not a record.","reason":"invalid"}],"index":0}]
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$DatasetServiceImpl.insertAll(BigQueryServicesImpl.java:1262)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$DatasetServiceImpl.insertAll(BigQueryServicesImpl.java:1281)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BatchedStreamingWrite.flushRows(BatchedStreamingWrite.java:403)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BatchedStreamingWrite.access$900(BatchedStreamingWrite.java:67)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BatchedStreamingWrite$BatchAndInsertElements.finishBundle(BatchedStreamingWrite.java:286)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BatchedStreamingWrite$BatchAndInsertElements$DoFnInvoker.invokeFinishBundle(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.finishBundle(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1776)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PTransformFunctionRegistry.lambda$register$0(PTransformFunctionRegistry.java:116)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.ProcessBundleHandler.processBundle(ProcessBundleHandler.java:560)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient.delegateOnInstructionRequestType(BeamFnControlClient.java:150)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient$InboundObserver.lambda$onNext$0(BeamFnControlClient.java:115)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UnboundedScheduledExecutorService$ScheduledFutureTask.run(UnboundedScheduledExecutorService.java:163)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use `STREAMING_INSERTS` instead of recommended `STORAGE WRITE API`. I recommend using https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api -